# String to Bytes Conversion-If already byte and taking it as string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, byte, ibm-mq, mq

I have a tibco activity which is giving this output in Byte.

Now i have to use this in my java code and send it to Mainframe Queue.

I am taking it as a `String bwmsg="wcLDxMXGx8="` and in my main method...

```
byte[] bArray = bwmsg.getBytes();
BytesMessage bytmsg = session.createBytesMessage(); 
bytmsg.writeBytes(bArray);
mqSender.sendToMQ(bytmsg,connection,sender,session);
```

`OUTPUT: 77634c44784d584778383d`

Am i doing wrong? 
Something which is already a byte I am reading it as a string and then again getting the bytes out of it and doing the workaround. Is this wrong?

If yes, can you please tell how can I take that `bwmsg` field as bytes and pass it on to the method.

I have Googled many links but not good help from them.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the string is base64-encoded. So you don't want to call `getBytes()` - you want to use a base64 decoder. You need to be much clearer about where and how conversions are occurring...

Comment: @JonSkeet:: Can you please confirm is that approach wrong?
I am getting byte...taking it as string,and then getting the bytes out of it and sending them.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting byte"? You're being much too vague here. All we can see is that you've started off with a *string* (`String bwmsg = ...`)

Comment: @JonSkeet:I have started with a string..but i am getting that from other system which is tibco BW.Where this output was in bytes...i am assuming it as string and then reading the bytes out of it.If i can directly take bytes in places of that String bwmsg,please let me know.

Comment: tibco BW is an SOA framework. I usually use generated classes for SOA communication, which do the conversion between e.g. base64 encoded PC Data in SOA messages to byte[] variables in java. If you parse SOA messages by hand, you have to do the conversions yourself (e.g. Java 8 offers java.util.Base64.getDecoder()). 
Could you share a bit more information about your setup? How do you receive the data via tibco BW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Jon Skeet in the above comment.I am just putting his words into code.

USE **javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter**

`static String bwmsg="wcLDxMXGx8="
static byte[] array = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(bwmsg);`

And in the main method ,make the above fields static so that you can call them directly in main method.
`public static void main(String [] args){
//other code here
.
.
BytesMessage bytmsg = session.createBytesMessage(); 
bytmsg.writeBytes(array);
mqSender.sendToMQ(bytmsg,connection,sender,session);`

This solved my purpose hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Base64.  This is simple programming 101.

You started with a string then converted it to a byte array and finally you printed out the byte array.

What do you expect to see?  You should expect to see a byte array.
i.e.
"wcLDxMXGx8=" is "77634c44784d584778383d"

Let me spell it out:

```
"w" = 0x'77'
"c" = 0x'63'
"L" = 0x'4c'
"D" = 0x'44'
"x" = 0x'78'
"M" = 0x'4d'
"X" = 0x'58'
"G" = 0x'47'
"x" = 0x'78'
"8" = 0x'38'
"=" = 0x'3d'
```

If you want it in human-readable format then convert the byte array back to a string and then print it out.

i.e. new String(bytmsg)

Comment: who told you it has nothing to take anything with Base64.Jon Skeet is corrct above.